# AclFileAttributeView on HFS+

Tags: java, macos, acl

I can't seem to get any information about if it is possible to use AclFileAttributeView for HFS+ ACLs on OS X 10.9 with Java 7 or 8.

What I extract from the [API docs](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html), those are meant to map NFSv4 ACLs. But I can use it on a Windows 7 to read NTFS ACLs as well.

I checked, if my filesystem has ACLs switched on by a simple `ls -le ~`:

`drwx------+  3 emKay  staff   102  6 Aug 11:39 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  5 emKay  staff   170 23 Jul 10:09 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 13 emKay  staff   442  7 Aug 14:16 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete`

Testing the supported `FileAttributeViews` with

`for (String viewName : localFile.getFileSystem().supportedFileAttributeViews()) {
    System.out.println(viewName);
}`

Results in:

`basic
posix
unix`

Did I miss anything in the documentation saying that this is not possible at all? Am I simply holding it wrong? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it's not supported. Nor is it supported in Linux. It's a bit of a pain as it means you have to dip into JNA/JNI to get it working.

> As of JDK 11, this interface(`AclFileAttributeView`) has only been implemented for Solaris and Windows. All other platforms will return null when interrogated for this interface.

Comment: All right, I thought so, but wanted to be sure. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you know, why it is not supported on Linux, as it is designed for NFS I would have thought it would also work e.g. on an ext filesystem?

Comment: When I discovered it didn't work on OSX or Linux I was surprised, but based on the AclEntryPermission class and the NFSv4 spec I don't believe that the ACL implementation on those platforms covers enough of permission granularity that is expressed in the API. Mind you, I could be reading too much into that, and it may just have been a simple matter of lack of resources to actually implement it.